# JsResult - Monad or Applicative?

Tags: scala, monads, applicative, playframework-json

My understanding of *one* of the distinctions between `Monad` and `Applicative` is that `flatMap` is available on `Monad`, but not `Applicative`.

If that's true, I'm confused by these Scala Play JSON [docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1-RC4/ScalaJsonCombinators):

> So what’s interesting there is that JsResult[A] is a monadic structure
>   and can be used with classic functions of such structures:
>
> flatMap[X](f: A => JsResult[X]): JsResult[X]
>
> etc

But, then the docs go on to say:

> Please note that JsResult[A] is not just Monadic but Applicative
>   because it cumulates errors. This cumulative feature makes JsResult[T]
>   makes it not very good to be used with for comprehension because
>   you’ll get only the first error and not all.

Since, as I understand, a `for-comprehension` is syntactic sugar for `flatMap`, how can `JsResult` be both a `Applicative` and `Monad`?

Comment: Take a look at Scalaz `Validation` to see exactly what this means.

Comment: @wheaties, ah it's covered in the book (Functional Programming in Scala) exercise that I've worked on - https://github.com/kman007us/side-work/blob/master/MonadsSbt/src/main/scala/Applicative/ValidationApplicative.scala. It's the same, yea? So you can perform validation and read *all* errors via `Monad` or `Applicative`?

Comment: I'm actually not going to answer this question 'cause I'm sure I'd screw it up. Add in `Monad` and `Applicative` to your tags and I bet a few more eyeballs will answer. Basically, all an `Applicative` adds is two more methods `pure` and `<*>`. The latter is what "solves" the issue of chaining the exceptions (provided they're held in a `Semigroup`.)

Comment: Also, read this: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal

Comment: See also [this recent conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scalaz/R-YYRoqzSXk/_wUp0XGQNqwJ) about Scalaz's `\/` (which is monadic and does not accumulate errors) and `Validation` (which isn't monadic and does). In short, when you have a monad you also have an applicative functor, and there are some good reasons to avoid the approach Play takes (having different monadic and applicative behaviors for the same type).

Answer (score 4):

`Monad` is a subclass of an `Applicative`. `Applicative`'s [`apply`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.functional.Applicative) is weaker operation than `flatMap`. Thus `apply` could be implemented in terms of `flatMap`.

**But**, in the `JsResult` (or actually `Reads`) case, it has special implementation which exploits `Applicative` computation's static form.

E.g. the two definitions below behave equivalently with correct JSON, yet `Applicative` (which uses `and`) have better error messages in erroneous cases (e.g. mentions if both `bar` and `quux` are invalid):

```
val applicativeReads: Reads[Foo] = (
  (__ \ "bar").read[Int] and
  (__ \ "quux").read[String]
)(Foo.apply _)

val monadicReads: Reads[Foo] = for {
  bar <- (__ \ "bar").read[Int]
  quux <- (__ \ "quux").read[String]
} yield Foo(bar, quux)
```